# Passing Hadoop config

Tags: hadoop

Please excuse me if this question is too trivial, but I would like to check this out, just in case.

I'm having a series of MR jobs where for each job there are parameters and there are parameters of my own.

Instead of passing arguments through method signatures I would like to pass configuration object and each method will read from that configuration.

My question is - is there a reason why not to use Hadoop Configuration class for passing my own parameters for methods, when it already exists?

The answer would be something like - there's nothing bad to it, or on the other hand - don't do that, Configuration is by default created with many default parameters and you don't want to pass such a "heavy" object just to convey your own parameters.

Comment: What is your reference for this statement: "don't pass such a "heavy" object" ? I have not heard such thing at all. But you can use setup() method in your Mapper to pass configuration.

Comment: The thing is, I'm not talking about passing parameters to Mappers, but to convey the parameters for methods in my application (to setup multiple drivers, concretely). That is why I'm asking whether it is a good or bad practice to do so.

Comment: Talk technical. Who claim that it will be heavy at first?

Comment: I'm asking whether it is heavy and whether it makes sense to use it? My reasoning is that might have a lot of default parameters at first, so I wanted to check that out. Also, I was considering whether it be bad software design to use that Configuration object for code not regarding MR, or I should create a class for my one for that, or use something like properties. Hence the "design" tag in my question.